# Is there a way to match across rows and columns in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following dataset in snowflake with two columns - user and matched user. I want to traverse through the table via matched_user and assign the same user value if a match is found.
For example, user1000 matches user100 and user 100 matches user200,user1000 so user1000 gets assigned to these three users. While, for user2000 there is no match. Is there an efficient way to achieve this without procedural code and loops?

```
user   | matched_user| Desired Output
user1000|   user100 | User1000
user1000|   user1000| User1000
user200 |   user200 | User1000
user200 |   user100 | User1000
user100 |   user100 | User1000
user100 |   user200 | User1000
user100 |   user1000| User1000
user2000|   user2000| user2000
```

Comment: What happens when when your scenario above happens twice but one time with user1000 (--> user1000 is assigned) and one time with user4000 (--> user4000 is assigned) at the same time?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements. Why would the row `user200 | user100` have an output of `User1000` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph traversal problem.

You can use a recursive CTE for this.  Start at the top and work your way down.  Because you have cycles, this is rather tricky.  I don't have Snowflake on hand to test, but the logic is like this:

```
with recursive tt as (
      select usr, matched_user from t
      union  -- on purpose to get bidirectional edges
      select matched_user, usr from t
     ), 
     cte as (
      select usr, matched_user, usr as desired, to_array('') as visited, 1 as lev
      from tt t
      union all
      select t.usr, t.matched_user, cte.desired, array_concat(cte.visited, t.usr), cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           tt t
           on t.usr = cte.matched_user
      where lev < 5 and
            array_position(t.usr, cte.visited,) is null
     )
select usr, max(desired)
from cte
group by usr;
```

This assigns the `desired` column on the *per user* level.  You can join back to the original data, if you need this with the edge details.  Also, the `desired` for the first group is `user200` because that is the maximum value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6e31e92b0971c84c5fbeb4e2fb0f8801) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.